# How do I stop NaN from appearing in my text file c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a piece of code that involves getting the average of 3 variables (skiTime1, skiTime2, and skiTime3), and saving it as the variable `skiTime`. The 3 variables and the average are saved into a text file. I asked a question on here previously, but I keep getting the text "NaN" in my text file where `skiTime` (the average) should be.

```
List<string> skiTime1 = new List<string>();
List<string> skiTime2 = new List<string>();
List<string> skiTime3 = new List<string>();

public string CalculateAverage(List<string> skiTime1, List<string> skiTime2, List<string> skiTime3)
{
    List<string> allValues = new List<string>();
    allValues.AddRange(skiTime1);
    allValues.AddRange(skiTime2);
    allValues.AddRange(skiTime3);
    float totalcount = 0;
    float average = 0;

    foreach (var value in allValues)
    {
        totalcount = totalcount + float.Parse(value);
    }

    average = totalcount / allValues.Count();
    return average.ToString();
}
```

the variable is going into the text file with the code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("pupilSkiTimes.txt", true))
{
    string loginDetails = addSkiTimesPupilCB.Text + "~" + addSkiTimesTime1TB.Text + "~" + addSkiTimesTime2TB.Text + "~" + addSkiTimesTime3TB.Text + "~" + skiTime;
    sw.WriteLine(loginDetails);
    sw.Close();
}
MessageBox.Show("Time has been recorded");
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger to verify that the average it's calculating is actually correct, *before* it writes that value to the file?

Comment: `average = totalcount / allValues.Count();` this code would never compile to get the exception. This is CS1955, try correcting to see if it works now.

Comment: @ExplodatedFaces: It should be fine if there's a `using` directive for `System.Linq`...

Answer (score 0):

General speaking there are 2 issues,

1. Can you ensure all your string values can be parsed to float, what happens when it is empty or null or none parsable value.
2. Does The sum of `totalCount` would exceed the float max value limit?

Anyway, I would use Try Parse and validate my numbers.

so in your loop make the following changes:

instead of this

```
foreach (var value in allValues)
{
    totalcount = totalcount + float.Parse(value);
}
```

change it to this

```
foreach (var value in allValues)
{
    bool isParsable = float.TryParse(value, out float number);
    if (isParsable)
    {
        totalcount += number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, where should i add these changes, could you post the full thing with these changes added because I don't know where that should go.

Comment: I don't really understand what parsing is, but the numbers are whole numbers.

Comment: what do you mean by you do not understand what parsing means?

Comment: Maybe you need also to provide a simple example of the numbers and the output.

Comment: The text file reads like this: ID~Name~skiTime1~skiTime2~skiTime3~skiTime

Comment: for example, it should look like: 2~john~32~33~34~33, but what i'm getting is: 2~john~32~33~34~NaN

Comment: It's giving me an error saying: the name totalCount does not exist in this current context, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just write totalcount, I correct the answer

Answer (score 0):

This version has some optimizations:

```
public static string CalculateAverage(List<string> skiTime1, List<string> skiTime2, List<string> skiTime3)
{
    float sum = 0.0f;
    int count = 0;

    var allLists = new[] { skiTime1, skiTime2, skiTime3 };
    foreach (var list in allLists)
    {
        foreach (var text in list)
        {
            float value;
            if (float.TryParse(text, out value))
            {
                sum += value;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    var average = count == 0 ? 0.0f : sum / count;
    return average.ToString();
}
```

The methods is static because it's not needed an instance of the class.

I use a list with 3 items (the lists parameters) instead of create a list and copy all the elements of the other lists (that usually will be more items).

Also, I use a variable to count the valid numbers instead of use the Count() method that meybe wrong if any of the items are not a number (you Count every item)

Comment: It still shows NaN instead of a number

Comment: I changed the special case in which the lists are empty. In that case, the average is NaN (not a number) but you can return whatever you prefer for this case. Zero or empty string, for example

Comment: where is the special case, I dont really understand what any of this code means, what should I change

Comment: The average assignment has a condition for count = 0. The first for is to iterate through all lists. The second for is to iterate each list value (the numbers). We try to convert any value to number. If we can, we add to sum variable and count one more valid number. At last, if we have 0 values, we return 0. In other case, we calculate the average

Comment: I honestly don't know why this isn't working then. Maybe the problem is with my streamWriter

Comment: Do I need to add something to skiTime?

Comment: Check your loginDetails variable to see which of components is NaN. Also, you can use System.IO.File.AppendAllLines instead of the stream (it's not the problem, but maybe easier to use)